# How to understand CPU 100% overnight on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, cpu-usage

I've a server with serval VM. Two of those (are the same replica) tonight had a spike in the usage of the CPU. They went both to 100% for 6 hours or so (we have Grpahite and we check the chart every morning). Then everything back to normal.

I checked the log and nothing strange is there.

Is there a way to get a kind of `top` command but over the data of this night? i would like to now what was the process that used all the CPUs.

Comment: Server? Exposed to the evil outside world? Did you check the firewall logs? Search the file system for newly modified files... my first concern would be that it was an attack which might have been successful.

Comment: Yes, exposed to the evil outside. the fact is that are 2 VM machines which host django, nothing on the other 5. how can i check the last modified files?

Comment: `man find` is your friend, presumably with the `-cnewer file` or `-ctime n` options. Good luck.

Comment: yup, i was using `ctime` but i've to skip some folders or there are too many results. thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do `top` post-factum, but you can log `top -l 1` every, say, 30 minutes to get equivalent.

As for what to do - inspect if the system was compromised, old packages with known vulnerabilities, unusual activity in logs if they were not wiped